# How to get static member of extended class

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I want to override `operator+` for my classes Fridge and TV (to make it add power consumption), so I made them extend Rtv class which should override that operator, however I don't know how to get proper `POWER_CONSUMPTION` field value if both Fridge and TV have different overriden value.
To be more precise i want to achieve this to be possible:

```
  Fridge fridge = new Fridge();
  Tv tv = new Tv();
  int totalPowerConsumptionOfFridgeAndTv = fridge + tv;
```

My idea for Rtv class was:

```
  class Rtv
{
    private const int pOWER_CONSUMPTION= 0;

    public static int POWER_CONSUMPTION=> pOWER_CONSUMPTION;

    public static int operator+ (Rtv a, Rtv b)
    { 
        return a.GetType().POWER_CONSUMPTION + b.POWER_CONSUMPTION;
    }
}
```

But simply doesn't work.

Comment: Side note: while duplicate shows how to achieve what you are asking the example in the post is very strange - in no way I would expect TV+Fridge to work, and even if it would I'd expect somehting like "FurnitureList" as result and not a numeric value. You may want to reconsider your design if that sample actually reflects what you are doing. One also unlikely to expect PowerConsumption to be static property of a class based on real world data... probably virtual in base class - "ElectronicEquipment"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is my homework at university and have to work like I asked :( so PowerConsumption have to be static and it have to work like this... I know it's pointless and wrong

Comment: You  should ask you teacher / TA what this assignment is about - it does not look like an answer to any regular assignment I can think of.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov He's a little bit crazy... not even one person from my year (about 60 ppl) understand what he mean and he's not replying to our e-mails... my last homework was to create 10 question questionnaire that says what mood are you in and show picture of that mood in WindowsForms, however my problem stays unsolved becouse `a.GetType().GetProperty(POWER_CONSUMPTION);` doesnt work for me, or again i made it wrong

Comment: Add a non static property to read the static one. Then the problem becomes quite simple.